# I2C is not sending a repeated start

Tags: stm32, interrupt, i2c

I encountered a problem. I have an STM32F103C8T6 controller and I am trying to implement I2C communication using interrupts. The problem is that when I need to send a repeated start, it doesn't happen. ITBUFEN interrupts are disabled, I only use ITEVFEN interrupts. The sequence is as follows: Start - send address - send register address (to read from) - send repeated start. (The dashes represent entry into an interrupt). So, after sending the second start, nothing happens. However, if I read DR before sending the repeated start, it will be sent.

```
(void)I2C2->DR;
I2C2->CR1|=I2C_CR1_START;
```

Yes, there is another option. After setting the start condition, you can write some garbage data to the DR register, and then the start condition will occur. The garbage data will not be transmitted.

```
I2C2->CR1|=I2C_CR1_START;
I2C2->DR=0x55;
```

There is another option: when I send the last byte of the register address, if I immediately write a start, and then when I enter the interrupt to send the start and send it again, the start is sent. What could be the problem? What am I doing wrong? It feels like some flag is not being reset, which prevents the start from being sent. However, I checked with a debugger at that moment and did not see anything like that. I also tried to add a pause between sending the repeated start, but it did not help. The interrupt for sending the start is executed, but the start is not generated.

I read the registers that are responsible for I2C with the debugger, but when I read the debugger everything works, but when I run it on execution it stops

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but you may be interested to know that various (not all) of the HAL functions for I2C use a repeated start already. If you're doing this manually just to get the repeated start, maybe you don't need to.

Comment: I understand what can be done on the hal, but in this case I will not be able to figure out how it works. and I really want..

Comment: Try clearing all status register flags before setting repeated start. Also, before doing that, you can try to see what flags are set just before you send repeated start. Maybe will get some useful info about what's going on. Also, you didn't explain what specifically interrupt events you use (more detail about logic of I2C driver). It could be timing problem (sending repeated start while data is only being shifted out or something of that sort)

Comment: I read registers, even those that are reserved, stupidly into a variable before I count the register before sending the start and after, and these variables have not changed.
Regarding interrupts, only ITEVFEN is included, which gives interrupts on SB, ADDR, BTF events.

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered that the RESTART condition is only issued after reading or writing the data-register (DR).
That works because the read or write of DR is required to clear the BTF (Byte Transfer Finished) condition.
The BTF condition should be cleared anyway to avoid extra BTF interrupts.

[Reference manual RM0008](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf#page=779)
specifies how the BTF flag in I2C_SR1 is cleared:

> Cleared by software reading SR1 followed by either
> a read or write in the DR register or by hardware after
> a start or a stop condition in transmission or when PE=0."

To clear the BTF flag after testing the flag in SR1, it is indeed enough to read the DR with the statement below.

```
  (void)I2C1->DR;  // Clear BTF by reading DR.
```

When setting CR1.START after clearing BTF, the RESTART is send.

The fact that it worked when you used the debugger to check the status
of the registers is because the debugger has read the data-register DR.